# Does CMTime has any real application outside encoding and decoding media

Tags: swift, avfoundation, video-processing, core-media

I understand the concept of `CMTime` and what it does. In the nutshell, we have very tiny fractions of a second represented as floating point numbers. When added, they accumulate an error, which becomes significant as decoding / playback progresses. For example, summing up one million times `0.000001` gives us `1.000000000007918`. Okay, `CMTime` sounds like a great idea.

```
let d: Double = 0.000001
var n: Double = 0
for _ in 0 ..< 1_000_000 { n += d }
print(n)

// 1.000000000007918
```

However, when attempting to convert a random `Double` to and from `CMTime` the above error looks like a joke compared to the difference between the original `Double` and its `CMTime` value. You can guess what would that difference look like after adding these random `CMTime` values a million times!

```
import CoreMedia
print("Simple number after 1,000,000 additions and diff between random ")
print("number before/after converting to CMTime:")
print("add:", String(format: "%.20f", 1.000000000007918))
for _ in 0 ..< 10 {
    let seconds = Double.random(in: 0 ... 10)
    // Let's go with the max timescale!
    let time = CMTime(seconds: seconds, preferredTimescale: .max)
    print("dif:", String(format: "%.20f", seconds - time.seconds))
}

// Simple number after 1,000,000 additions and diff between random 
// number before/after converting to CMTime:
// add: 1.00000000000791811061
// dif: 0.00000000025481305954
// dif: 0.00000000027779378797
// dif: 0.00000000000071231909
// dif: 0.00000000024774449159
// dif: 0.00000000028195579205
// dif: 0.00000000029723601358
// dif: 0.00000000029402880131
// dif: 0.00000000044737191729
// dif: 0.00000000036750824606
// dif: 0.00000000043562398133
```

On the other hand, yes, if any given `Double` can be accurately converted to `CMTime`, then this wouldn't be an issue.

Question. I'm trying to figure out if it makes sense to use `CMTime` on its own for time handing (apart from a million additions, obviously) or is it only useful for working with APIs that take and return values in `CMTime` format? To give some context, I have a video editing app with bespoke UI (player, tracks, timelines) that deals with playback speed adjustments, track trimming and rearranging, etc. Using `Double` to express time values works out great, it's clean, simple and does the job. But `CMTime` feels like the "right" way to do it. However, seeing what happens to a `Double` after converting it back and forth makes me wonder `CMTime`'s field of use is as narrow as encoding and decoding media?

Comment: Don't post images post your code.

Comment: Good point. Done.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct. Using a screwdriver as a hammer may work most of the time, but it's not the best use. More importantly, it may be missing some non-obvious edge cases where it just won't work or will cause more work to hammer in the nail (such as double processing).

Secondly, what is your conversion method? Perhaps you are missing an edge case such as varying timescale. I can't really give further guidance without a bit more information.

CMTime is already frame-accurate with AVPlayer without conversion. That's what it was made for, though make sure you set toleranceBefore and toleranceAfter to zero.

Note: I've been working with frame-accurate video/audio processing for over a decade.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm familiar with tolerances and media processing/playback is not an issue. I'm mostly interested in theory. `CMTime` is a native CM struct to represent time, so I wanted to adapt it for the general media time representation, including cases when `CMTime` values don't come directly from CM. For example, a custom composition where user controls via UI frame rate and track duration – situation where I'd need to convert `Double` into `CMTime`, which won't accurately represent the original value…

Comment: Of course, such cases can be handled separately, but I get a feeling that `CMTime` might be an overkill. There are pros and cons, and I see it pretty much exactly as you describe. After converting everything to `CMTime` the internal API got clumsy and awkward to work with, while not necessarily more time-accurate. So, I wanted to hear thoughts of people who have better experience with it, perhaps there are other reasons to use `CMTime` that I'm not seeing, or there's something else obvious or important to keep in mind.

Comment: As you're probably aware, the timescale property of CMTime is meant for controlling frame rate and it could be set via a UI, as well as duration (obviously). 
Also thought you might like to know that I've implemented jumping to specific frames via CMTime and it is frame accurate. 
Good on you for keeping a healthy dose of skepticism, even about your own ideas. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you! :) Can you comment on the accuracy part? My understanding is the higher the `preferredTimescale` in `CMTime(seconds: seconds, preferredTimescale: .max)` the more accurate the `CMTime` representation is going to be, except for cases when the value can be clearly expressed as a rational number like `CMTime(seconds: 1.5, preferredTimescale: 60)`, i.e, `90/60`. I understand there's no efficient way for that in CM except for manual floating point to rational conversion?

Comment: Sorry I missed this comment! Apple uses a timescale of 600 for video, which is usually 30 fps. That would mean there is a range of 20 for each frame. If there are only 30 frames per second, setting a timescale to max (4294967295) would mean that each frame is represented by a very large, uneven value range ending in ".5", possibly causing a problem for you. It's also a bit of overkill. :-)

Comment: If your user marks a video when it is paused at a certain time/frame, just save that CMTime value and scale. When you want them to go back to that time, recreate it, then set the media player to that time. Using a video with timecode burn-in may help you in your dev testing.

Comment: Also, please accept my answer if it has solved your question. :-)